# Permiso de rol al momento de edit una entity en jhipster

Tags: maven, angular6, jhipster

Cordial Saludo

Soy nuevo en **Jhipster** y estoy creando un nuevo **rol para darle permisos**.

Los pasos que estoy corriendo son los siguiente:
1.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo el rol y lo include en `master.xml`

luego le doy `mvn liquibase:update`

y lo coloca en la base de datos en la tabla `jhi_authority`

Después corro la aplicacion con `mvn` y ingreso como **admin** y creo un usuario con ese nuevo rol creado, después ingreso con ese usuario que tiene el nuevo rol y quiero darle click en lo señalado y no puedo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- *Create a new Region*
- *view*
- *Edit*
- *Delete*

Que me falta para que el rol me deje hacer esas funcionalidades?

**Nota:** estoy utilizando la ultima version de jhipster

Answer (score 2):

Partiré del hecho que tienes un proyecto como el publicado en sus repositorios [jhipsterSampleApplication](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app) con la versión **JHipster 5.4.2**.

Al parecer el problema radica en el front-end ya que no te permite tener acceso a esa vista. Para ello debes editar tu archivo `region.route.ts` y añadir tu rol creado.

```
...
{
    path: 'region',
    component: RegionComponent,
    data: {
        authorities: ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_PQRS'],
        pageTitle: 'jhipsterSampleApplicationApp.region.home.title'
    },
    canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
},
...
```

**NOTA**

Para añadir el rol lo estás haciendo bien pero hay que aclarar *Liquibase* es un complemento para añadir versionamiento a tu Base de Datos pero se pudo realizar esta acción insertando directamente el registro utilizando SQL o añadiendo el rol en el archivo `authorities.csv` incluido en el proyecto.

Otro punto a tener en cuenta es la configuración en el archivo `SecurityConfiguration.java` en el método `public void configure(HttpSecurity http)`

```
...
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/init").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/finish").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated() // Esta línea permite que tu usuario realice peticiones al back-end
        .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
...
```

En este archivo se encuentra la configuración que tiene tu back-end para permitir a los usuarios realizar peticiones. Esto en caso de que quieras restringir ciertos *end-points* a un rol en específico.